# Increasing values in a numpy matrix that are below a certain indice

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to calculate a cumulative probability counting using 2D numpy matrices. When an object has value x for x-axis and y for y-axis, I add to the cells which has an index less than or equal to (x,y)

i.e. the object has 1,1 in a 3x3 index cell. The matrix should look like this:

```
[1][1][0]
[1][1][0]
[0][0][0]
```

The problem is, I cannot do it by simply indexing like `matrix[:1][:1]`.

If possible. I do not want to switch to other library than numpy because it requires too many work. Is there any pythonic way to do it without using daunting for loops?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the indexing *in one step*, i.e `[i_expr,j_expr]` not `[i_expr][j_expr]`. (The `[][]` form only works for scalar indices and even there is bad style.) You also have to add 1 if you want to include the boundaries.

```
>>> bins = np.zeros((5, 5), int)
>>> i, j = 1, 1
>>> bins[:i+1, :j+1] += 1
>>> bins
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```